# ASP .NET Cookie too large after following microsoft tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I am following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3
which basically adds custom claims to the user identity after login. One of the claims is the users profile picture which is stored as a base64 string. This however makes the cookie too large and the webserver fails to load the site. This is the code for adding the picture:

```
var photo = await graphClient.Me
                                .Photo
                                .Content
                                .Request()
                                .GetAsync();



var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
photo.CopyTo(memoryStream);
var photoBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

photoUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes)}";
```

The photo is fetched from the Microsoft Graph API and is returned as a Stream which I convert to base64 string. Am I missing something? Any assistance will be really appreciated.

Comment: How big is the picture file once converted to Base64? Cookies have a limit of 4096 bytes. Please refer to the documentation: [Asp.Net Cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178194(v=vs.100)) You could always save the image in Session.

Comment: Hey, well the image is pretty big its 58k bytes. This however became an issue today, yesterday it worked fine. The only difference are some windows 10 updates, which I suspect have something to do with the issue.

Comment: Cookies sent as headers, kestrel has default limit of 32KB that you can increase if needed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits?view=aspnetcore-6.0#:~:text=Gets%20or%20sets%20the%20maximum%20allowed%20size%20for%20the%20HTTP,32%2C768%20bytes%20(32%20KB).

Comment: @Artur Browsers, however, tend to have a limit around 4096 bytes (4KB) per origin: https://chromestatus.com/feature/4946713618939904 : "user agents are now required to limit the sum of the lengths of the cookie's name and value to 4096 bytes, and limit the length of each cookie attribute value to 1024 bytes"

Comment: @Dai you are right. But the limit of 4KB is for single cookie. Asp.Net Core automatically splits cookie bigger than 4KB into chunks. I believe the problem of the OP is total size of all cookies sent to the server exceeding max `MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize`

Comment: @Dai I can't attach screenshot to comment but I have a single cookie with size 4002 on my browser right now.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that I didn't compress the image when fetching it from the API. The following code resolved the issue:

```
var photo = await graphClient.Me
    .Photos["48x48"]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
photo.CopyTo(memoryStream);
var photoBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

photoUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes)}";
```

The indexing on the Photos array is the key.

Comment: This is still a very bad approach: Cookies should never exceed 1-4KB in size, but most images are going to be 10KB+. You should not be storing large values in cookies at all, whether using `data:` URIs nor Base64 encoding. Instead store the image data in some publicly accessible cache (over HTTPS) and store a _reference_ to that blob.